# Do Response.Redirect in aspx markup

Tags: .net, response.redirect

I have a .net button that should do a Response.Redirect. Can I do it in the markup?

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick='<%# Response.Redirect("~/Administration.aspx"); %>' Text="Cancel"></asp:Button>
```

It does not work because "cannot implicitly convert void to object"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign code directly like that. You need to assign it to a method that handles the event, like:

```
OnClick="btn1_Click"

protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Administration.aspx");
}
```

**EDIT**

What you can do is skip ASP.NET altogether and do it with regular HTML and javascript, to avoid your post:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Administration.aspx") %>'">
```